# where is signingReport?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, android-studio, gradle

I can't get SHA-1

I want to get it and connect it with firebase

[image]

Comment: Which android studio version do you use now?

Comment: @ChiragThummar  Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Patch 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a intended behaviour from android studio. because of gradle build task list populate make project build slower so default it is disabled.

You can enable it by going `File -> Settings -> Experimental` and `uncheck Configure all gradle task during Sync(this can make gradle slower)` and then sync the project `File -> Sync Project with Gradle Files`. If the problem is still there, just reboot Android Studio

**Steps**

[image: gradle]